# NSDateFormatter not converting NSString properly

Tags: ios, ios5, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Simple case of trying to prove I can convert `NSString` to `NSDate`. Create an `NSDate`, turn it into an `NSString`, then back into an `NSDate`. The date looks fine as a string, but when I convert it back I always get some date like 12/25/2011 .... Can someone spot my error?

```
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YY hh:mm a"];
 NSDate* b = [[NSDate alloc] init];
 NSString* f = [df stringFromDate:b]; // has the current date and time
 NSDate* dt =[df dateFromString:f];  // 12/25/2011 - where does it get this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mma"]; // or @"dd/MM/yy hh:mma"
```

This is the result:

```
Printing description of b:
2012-06-12 13:06:16 +0000
Printing description of dt:
2012-06-12 13:06:00 +0000
```

If you need more info I suggest to read [date-formatter-examples](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatter-examples.html).

If you don't use ARC make attention to memory leaks. For example, use `[NSDate date]` instead of `[[NSDate alloc] init]`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like your system is using a Datestyle.

May you should set the formatter to use no style:

`[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];`

And why you are not using the style in general? It seems like the `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`  is what you want. You only have to set the time style as well and use `setLocal:` to bring the date in the order you want.